# Cosmos Emulator running in Docker container does not export certificate

Tags: docker, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to run the Cosmos emulator in a docker container, following the instructions [on the docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator/).
When I start run the container:

```
md $env:LOCALAPPDATA\CosmosDBEmulatorCert 2>null
docker run -v $env:LOCALAPPDATA\CosmosDBEmulatorCert:C:\CosmosDB.Emulator\CosmosDBEmulatorCert -P -t -i -m 2GB microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator
```

I see the expected output. However, the documentation says that

> After starting the Emulator container you will find two forms of the certificate at %LOCALAPPDATA%\azure-cosmosdb-emulator.hostd:

I see nothing, and no files are written to the directory. When I try to import the certificate, there is nothing to import. How do I get the emulator to import the SSL certificate?

Comment: Can you run certlm.msc and under Personal > Certificates, see if there is a  certificate issued to Localhost with the friendly name: DocumentDbEmuatorCeritifcate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#export-the-ssl-certificate

Comment: Additional information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator-export-ssl-certificates